# What is the best way to insert macros, snippets or code blocks into XAML view?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, code-snippets

I would like to make a time-saving **snippet to pop in blocks of XAML** like this and then just change the values (like you can in code with e.g. **"cw"-TAB or "foreach"-TAB**):

```
<Style x:Key="FirstCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
</Style>
```

But snippets **don't seem to work in XAML** view.

I'm **currently using [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software//lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php)** to insert chunks which works anywhere in Windows, but the Visual Studio code completion gets in the way when the text is inserted in XAML view.

**What are some solutions that you use** to expedite your verbose XAML coding, e.g. inserting macros, snippets, code chunks etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting snippets to work in XAML, but they work in the typical XML way, that is you have to type in the brackets around the snippet name.

Not as nice as the code-behind w/Intellisense, but it works OK.  Never tried Texter, that may work better...